# From a vector containing different objects, how to call the correct function?

Tags: c++

I have classes such as ...

```
class BaseNode { 
    // ...

    public:
        virtual void save(std::ofstream &);
};

class InputNode : public BaseNode { ... } // no virtual save
class BiasNode : public BaseNode { ... } // no virtual save
```

And I store them on this vector ...

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseNode>> nodes;

nodes.push_back(make_shared<BaseNode>(InputNode()));
nodes.push_back(make_shared<BaseNode>(BiasNode()));
```

But the following doesn't work ...

```
for (auto n = nodes.begin(); n != nodes.end(); ++n) 
    n->save(outfile);

../../../../src/libs/ann/base-net.cpp:40:6: error: ‘class std::shared_ptr<BaseNode>’ has no member named ‘save’
```

Yet BaseNode does have a save() function and I feel like I'm doing something wrong in my iterations.

I do have other classes that inherit from BaseNode that do include their own virtual save functions, but in this case (where InputNode and BiasNode to not define their own) I want InputNode and BiasNode to call BaseNode::save().

Thoughts?

Comment: Make shared does not work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodes.begin()` returns an iterator, therefore you need to dereference the iterator to get to the object.

```
for (auto n = nodes.begin(); n != nodes.end(); ++n)
    (*n)->save(outfile);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/HcClHr)

Also just a tip:  Make the parameter to `save` a `std::ostream&`.  This gives the `save` function more flexibility if the output stream is not a file.

Answer (score 1):

You should dereference the iterator.

There are two ways to solve your problem: the easiest is:

```
for (auto n: nodes) 
      n->save(outfile);
```

The other is to convert the iterator into a reference to the element of the vector (a pointer to the object):

```
for (auto n = nodes.begin(); n != nodes.end(); ++n) {
   auto &el = *n;
   el->save(outfile);
}
```

But, why do you store pointers? why don't you simply store the objects themselves in the vector?

```
std::vector<BaseNode> nodes;
nodes.push_back(BiasNode());
nodes.push_back(InputNode());

for (auto n: nodes) 
   n.save();
```

Comment: The first version will create copies of `std::shared_ptr<>`, which is probably expensive in a performance critical part of the code.

Comment: sure. if that important then change the for(auto n: nodes) to for(auto &n: nodes).

Comment: This will also not give him run time polymorphism support.

Comment: I tested it (at least under C++-14) it does not. It all depends on the pointer. In fact, this: nodes.push_back(make_shared<BaseNode>(InputNode())); is what is losing the polymorphism in his code. The make_shared should be of type InputNode, not BaseNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto n = nodes.begin(); n != nodes.end(); ++n) 
    n->save(outfile); //here's the issue
```

Here, n is the iterator. Dereference it to use like this :

```
(*n)->save(outfile);
```

Or simply (after C++11)

```
for (auto n : nodes) 
    n->save(outfile);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
TYPE& dynamic_cast<TYPE&> (object);
```

To try to figure out the class that you are calling in your loop, then call the method for the class that you expect to have it.